# Add group to Proxy User

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm using Django with Wagtail CMS and i created two proxy models from class User. I ant to add a group on user creation from the proxy classes. I tried to add signals but that apparently dose not work on proxy models.

So on save i would like to add teachers to `Teachers` group and students to `Students`

```py
#models.py
class User(AbstractUser):

    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        STUDENT = "STUDENT", "Student"
        TEACHER = "TEACHER", "Teacher"

    type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=50, choices=Types.choices, default=Types.STUDENT)

class Student(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy: True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.type = User.Types.STUDENT
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Teacher(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy: True  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.type = User.Types.TEACHER
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it at the end of the `save` method:

```
class Student(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy: True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        creating = not self.pk
        if creating:
            self.type = User.Types.STUDENT
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if creating:
            self.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='Students'))
```